# ASP.NET cookies in Mobile and Tablet PC

Tags: android, asp.net, ipad, mobile, session-cookies

Funny problem has occurred... I'm developing ASP.NET Web site and there is one issue, which I can't explain. I've tried to google it, but no success.

Main problem is: I've defined a button exit for users and I'm using session, which uses cookies ( I'm using such mechanism of the session, because cookieless session won't allow users from one external IP address to authorize at my server, that's why I'm using it to allow users to use my website from one external IP, but if they have different internal IPs ) mechanism.

So on PC I can exit from website and cookies values are cleaning.
But my friend have tried to access website from Android on his smartphone and iPad.

All works fine except exit function. He said, that from PC all works, but from iPad or Android phone he can't exit. He authorizes in website, can do all things, which he can on PC, but can't exit.

I wonder, what could appear, that exactly from iPad/Android smartphone it's impossible to exit.

Any suggestions?

PS, piece of code:

```
void btnQuit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    string[] myCookies = Request.Cookies.AllKeys;

    foreach (string cookie in myCookies)
    {
        Response.Cookies[cookie].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    }

    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some codes?

Comment: @HaroldJavier the source code of cleaning cookies is upper, I've edited the topic content.